# Nested loop append to file

Tags: vbscript

I'm using a piece of software called Chronoscan which uses VBScript.

I am attempting to create and append to a file, which in part is successful. However, I am trying to place an argument based on a child table as to whether or not to export the data.

Firstly I am counting the number of records contained in a table named 'batch' (unique id) and looping this against the record number I am assigning variables, within this loop I have another loop which is doing the same for a child table named 'Grid' again assigning variables. I am then writing these variables to the file. Therefore I am writing a value for the number of records held in the child table for each record held in its parent.

What I actually want to do is to argue against the child table and only write records if it meets my argument.

The child table has a field called SkuType which has 3 possible values M, A or NULL.

My argument needs to be if the child table has a value of M write the record else don't, if the child table does not have a value of M in any of its records relating to it parent then only write the first record from the child table and ignore the remainder.

Please see below example of my code, which works fine for exporting ALL records from the child table.

```
Dim fso
Dim FilePathName
Dim FilePath
Dim NumDocs
Dim numRows
Dim Station
Dim StationDate
Dim StationTime
Dim StationName
Dim Exp

GridPanel = 1 'first panel
Set Batch = ChronoApp.GetCurrentBatch
CurrentBatchname = Batch.Getname
NumDocs = Batch.GetDocCount

'Set output filename and path here
Station = ChronoApp.GetVariableValue("station_user")
StationDate = Left(ChronoApp.GetVariableValue("station_date_full"), 10)
StationName = ChronoApp.GetVariableValue("station_name")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Loop the batch here
For numDoc = 0 To NumDocs-1
    FilePath = "C:\Users\" & Station & "\Google Drive\Driver Scans\ChronoPlans\" &_
        Left(Batch.GetUserField(numDoc, "Movement Date"),2) &_
        Mid(Batch.GetUserField(numDoc, "Movement Date"),4,2) &_
        Right(Batch.GetUserField(numDoc, "Movement Date"),2) & "\"

    FilePathName = FilePath & StationName & "_" & StationDate & ".CSV"

    If Not fso.FolderExists(FilePath) Then FSO.CreateFolder (FilePath) 'create folder if it does not exist
    Set inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePathName, 8, True)

    'Get header level fields here 
    StationTime= Left(ChronoApp.GetVariableValue("station_date_full"), 16)

    'Loop grid here   
    numRows = Batch.GetXgridRowCount (numDoc, GridPanel)
    For row = 0 To numRows-1
        'Get grid level fields here
        SkuType = Batch.GetXgridFieldValue (numDoc, GridPanel, row, "SkuType") 
'Get Serial
        SKU = Batch.GetXgridFieldValue (numDoc, GridPanel, row, "SKU") 

        'Write to file here
        inputFile.WriteLine(_
            Chr(34) & SKU & Chr(34) &  "," &_
            Chr(34) & StationTime & Chr(34)& "," &_
            Chr(34) & SkuType & Chr(34) )
    Next 'loop Grid
    inputFile.Close 
Next 'Loop Batch
'Now cleanup
inputFile.Close 
Set inputFile = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? What doesn't work the way you expected? SO is not a place where you post your requirements and we rewrite your code for you.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I'm not asking anyone to write the code, i'm asking for advice. If i remove the inner loop, i just geyt

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I'm not asking anyone to write the code, i'm asking for advice. If i remove the inner loop, i just get the records from the parent table, which is sort of what i want. 

I need to get the data from the child table that relates if SkuType = M or the first record if any related child record does not have an M

I have tried various ways of stating if SkuType <> M then reset the counter to 1 so that it only picks up the first record etc, none work.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You don't need to remove anything. You need to iterate over the grid rows twice: first to check if at least one of the "SkuType" values is "M", and then a second time if at there's at least one row with that SkuType. Alternatively you could postpone writing the output until after the loop, collect the output for each case in separate variables, and discard what isn't needed once you know what isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, i have solved the problem in the way suggested.